# Handlebars.js recursive precompilation

Tags: handlebars.js, precompile

Question, i'm trying to precompile my .handlebars files to templates.js.
So far it's working for all files in source dir, but not for files in a subdirectory (where i keep the partials).

The command i'm using:

```
handlebars -m resources/views/handlebars/> resources/assets/js/handlebars/templates.js
```

How can i make this recursive, so that it iterates all directories?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple:

```
handlebars resources/views/handlebars/ -f public/js/templates.js
```

Note, this also precompiles all partials that reside in a subdir.
To make these accessible in templates, add this line in beginning of your code:

```
Handlebars.partials = Handlebars.templates;
```

Since partials are also templates, this seems like a harmless solution, albeit not the most memory friendly one. If anyone has a suggestion for this..?

Now i want to delve into precompiling custom helpers... documentation is not very clear about that. I'll properly concat these with elixir.